# iOS Game Center Leaderboard scores are disappearing

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

I have a new game that I just released to the app store, and I'm having an issue with the Game Center Leaderboards. My app successfully posts scores to a leaderboard, and opening Game Center shows those scores as well. Then, after anywhere between 30min-2hrs later all of the scores on the Leaderboard disappear. Has anybody seen anything similar (in live Leaderboards, not Sandbox)?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my app that i released yesterday... Have you solved this issue? thanks.

Comment: I ended up deleting my leaderboard and setting it back up from scratch, making sure to set it to all time scores and add it to the next version in iTunesConnect. Annoying, but that did the trick for me.